# How to Re-Deploy a Contract to Ropsten using Truffle?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, dapp-development, tokens

I've deployed my initial contract: [My Token on Ropsten](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/token/0x2eb4f2352146aa5ce45f9ffdbc49735b9306f773?a=0x8d207982099e2c6047c6ab0b6ec3e5c69e726e68).

But I noticed that I've made a mistake, and I would like to make some changes on my smart contract. What is a common development workflow for this? Doesn't seem like I could "re-deploy" it:

```
➜  LYKECOIN git:(master) ✗ truffle deploy --network ropsten
Using network 'ropsten'.

Network up to date.
➜  LYKECOIN git:(master) ✗
```

I want to re-create an entirely new smart contract in Ropsten, not updating the last one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an option called `--reset` in Truffle that should force the redeployment of your contract [[more info](http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/commands#migrate)].

```
$ truffle deploy --network ropsten --reset
```